# Mount Remote Partition Locally?

Tags: partition, mount, remote

I have a Webserver, and I would like to move some of the static files for the web application off to a remote server, yet still have them accessible.

Is there a way to have (Server A) mount a folder from (Server B) as if it were a local drive?  Or simply a mounted partition?  Basically so my web app can write to the remote drive via something like /mount/remotefolder ??

Both servers are running CentOS, however in two geographically separate locations.

Answer (score 1):

`sshfs` is what you're looking for.  http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html  -- you can even use `fstab` entries to automount it on boot, or set it not to mount, but then you can just do `mount /pre/defined/mount/point` to mount it.  `sshfs` can be slow, but it's definitely secure.  It requires `fuse` to be active, either as a kernel module/compiled into kernel, or as a userspace program.

I have the following line in my `.bashrc`:

```
alias xxr-sfs="sshfs xxr:/var/www/localhost/htdocs ~/xxr"
```

And `xxr` is defined in my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host xxr
HostName xxr
user mark
```

(stuff above has obviously been renamed for my privacy)

Then if I want to mount it, I just type `xxr-sfs` to mount it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question would be NFS, I think. Alternatively, for a more fancy setup, you could have the two servers share a DRBD volume.

However, I wonder what's wrong with HTTP as a file access protocol? Can't server B have it's own web server and serve its files for itself? Split your webapp so that the part that processes the files resides on server B?

Update:

I didn't read OP carefully enough. If "geographically separate locations" means long latency, both drbd and nfs may be suboptimal, depending on the exact use case. If there is more than a 50 ms latency between the two locations, I would try to use different web servers that both talk directly to the end user, if possible.

Comment: Bandwidth in Australia is quite pricey, so I would like to move the non-critical elements such as Video and Media to a US based server whilst keeping the critical elements of the web app locally.